# Recursive functions in R: How do I save the output of every call to a vector?

Tags: r, recursion, vector

How can I save the output from each call to vector?
I have seen similar questions, but either poorly formulated or for more complicated problems. It would be helpful to me, and I am sure to other beginners, to see a solution for the most basic case.

For instance:

```
recursive = function(x) {
  if (x < 1) {
    print(x + 0.1)
    return(recursive(x + 0.1))
  }
}
recursive(0)

[1] 0.1
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.3
[1] 0.4
[1] 0.5
[1] 0.6
[1] 0.7
[1] 0.8
[1] 0.9
[1] 1
[1] 1.1
```

How can these outputs be directly compiled to a vector?

I tried appending to an empty vector, but R disapproved of this approach.

```
output <- c()
recursive = function(x) {
  if (x < 1) {
    output <- append(output, x + 0.1)
    print(x + 0.1)
    return(recursive(x + 0.1))
  }
}
recursive(0)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *super assignment* `<<-`. See the [the help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) and, for more in depth info, the [section 7.2.4](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html?q=%3C%3C-#super-assignment) of "Advanced R".

Basically, variables created/modified inside a function don't go to the main environment. To achieve that, you need `<<-`.

```
output <- c()
recursive = function(x) {
  if (x < 1) {
    output <<- append(output, x + 0.1)
    print(x + 0.1)
    return(recursive(x + 0.1))
  }
}
recursive(0)
output

 [1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1
```

**Edit:** As Onyambu pointed out, using `<<-` is dangerous and can lead to unwanted side effects to your code. I recommend going with his answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply concatenate the output. Note: Be careful on the use of `<<-`.

```
recursive = function(x) {
   if (x < 1)  c(x, recursive(x + 0.1))
   else x
 }

 recursive(0)
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1
```

If you need to explicitly use the `return` function, you do not need to use `else`:

```
recursive1 <- function(x) {
   if (x < 1)  return(c(x, recursive1(x + 0.1)))
   x
 }
 recursive1(0)
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1
```

Another way is to change the condition:

```
recursive2 <- function(x) {
   if (x > 1)  return(x)
   c(x, Recall(x + 0.1))
 }
 recursive2(0)
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1
```